# Streaming a zip download from cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase cloud function that uses express to streams a zip file of images to the client.  When I test the cloud function locally it works fine.  When I upload to firebase I get this error:

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

What could be causing this error? Memory limit?

```
export const zipFiles = async(name, params, response) => {


  const zip = archiver('zip', {zlib: { level: 9 }});


  const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles({prefix:`${params.agent}/${params.id}/deliverables`});

  if(files.length){
    response.attachment(`${name}.zip`);
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

    zip.pipe(output);

    response.on('close', function() { 
      return output.send('OK').end(); // <--this is the line that fails
  });

  files.forEach((file, i) => {

    const reader = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(file.name).createReadStream();
    zip.append(reader, {name: `${name}-${i+1}.jpg`});

  });
  zip.finalize();
}else{
  output.status(404).send('Not Found'); 
}
```

Comment: That error message means quite literally what it says: your code is trying to send a header after it's already done that. I expect that it's the `send('OK')`, since that may be forcing the output stream's body to become text, where a zip file would be sent as a binary.

Comment: Removing ‘send(‘ok’)’. Won’t have any adverse effects?

Comment: I can't answer that for you, as it depends on the client that receives the zip. But the clients I can quickly think of are not looking for an `OK` string in the body when receiving a binary file. It's certainly worth trying, and then seeing if: 1) the file now makes it to your client, 2) if the clients deal with it in the way you want them to.

Answer (score 1):

What Frank said in comments is true.  You need to decide all your headers, including the HTTP status response, before you start sending any of the content body.

If you intend to express that you're sending a successful response, simply say `output.status(200)` in the same way that you did for your 404 error.  Do that up front.  When you're piping a response, you don't need to do anything to close the response in the end.  When the pipe is done, the response will automatically be flushed and finalized.  You're only supposed to call [end()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end) when you want to bail out early without sending a response at all.

Bear in mind that Cloud Functions only supports a maximum payload of 10MB ([read more about limits](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits)), so if you're trying to zip up more than that total, it won't work.  In fact, there is no "streaming" or chunked responses at all.  The entire payload is being built in memory and transferred out as a unit.

Comment: Welp, crap.  I'm trying to build ~100MB zips. Are there any alternatives you could suggest for how to work around this?

Comment: Write the zip back to storage, give them a direct URL for it, and arrange for it to be deleted some time later.