# Firebase Function fails with `Couldn't handle response` for Archive

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to zip a few audio files from a bucket, then download the zip on Firebase functions, everything works well on local emulator, also raised memory to 1Gb and 300 for timeout, but the https function fails with a generic message, "Couldn't handle response".

Here's the code.

```
const workingDir = join(tmpdir(), 'zip' + +new Date());
await fs.ensureDir(workingDir);
const archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 9 } });

archive.on('warning', function (err) {
    if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
        console.log('Warning', err);
    } else {
        throw err;
    }
});

archive.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('error', err);
    throw err;
});

res.attachment(+new Date() + '.zip').type('zip');

archive.pipe(res);
archive.on('end', () => res.end());
archive.directory(workingDir, false);
archive.finalize();
```

Comment: Line 1 has `'zip' + + new Date()`.  I suspect the double `+` is a typo or something?

Comment: @GregFenton, nah I'm converting date to number like that, otherwise it would be date in string format, might this be causing the issue somehow?

Comment: Ah, okay.  I try to be more explicit in casting a Date to a number, but I see what you are doing.  Are you seeing anything in the Functions logs (Firebase Console >> Functions >> Logs) ?

Comment: Yes, I see a log, that's actually my issue, it simply ends with an error, "Couldn't handle response", nothing more,  this only happens when deployed, on local emulator it works.

Comment: is it possible you are ending the response before its received? I suspect that the client isn't able to handle the result in time.

Comment: Bailing out, apparent this cannot be done, at least not this way on firebase since the files I'm zipping are over 10MB, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54381610/streaming-a-zip-download-from-cloud-functions